# How to display API information on a page

Tags: javascript, html, api, fetch-api

I am working on creating a simple page that displays current free game giveaways using this API. https://gamerpower.p.rapidapi.com/api/giveaways?type=game&sort-by=popularity

However, I am still very new at working with APIs and am not sure if what I've been searching for is the right direction. The sources that I've been looking at haven't made much sense, and any examples I've tried to follow still result in an Uncaught Reference error telling me that the variable I am trying to use isn't defined.

Here is my very messy and basic code.

```
const gamesList = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': '<API-KEY>',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'gamerpower.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
};

fetch('https://gamerpower.p.rapidapi.com/api/giveaways?type=game&sort-by=popularity', gamesList)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data.gamesList))
        let games=data
        document.querySelector('h2').innerText=data.gamesList.title
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="This is where your description goes">
        <meta name="keywords" content="one, two, three">

        <title>Game Giveaways</title>

        <!-- external CSS link -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Current Game Giveaways</h1>
    
        <button type="button" name="button">Get Burger</button>

        <h2>Games</h2>
        <img src="" alt="">
        <h3>Description</h3>

        
        

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm sure I am just missing something incredibly simple, but after working on it longer than I want to admit, I still can't wrap my head around where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** In the future, do not share your API key with anyone.

You need to understand the response from the API call. I will demonstrate this to you using TypeScript types.

The response of the `/api/giveaways` call is a `Giveaway[]` ("object array" or "array of objects").

Here is a `Giveaway` object:

```
interface Giveaway {
  description: string,
  end_date: string,          // 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' or 'N/A'
  gamerpower_url: string,    // URL
  id: number,
  image: string,             // Resource URI
  instructions: string,      // HTML
  open_giveaway: string,     // URL
  open_giveaway_url: string, // URL
  platforms: string,         // CSV
  published_date: string,    // 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' or 'N/A'
  status: string,            // e.g. 'Active'
  thumbnail: string,         // Resource URI
  title: string,
  type: string,              // e.g. 'Game'
  users: number,             // user count
  worth: string              // Currency in USD
}
```

Now that we understand the response of the API call, we know that we are dealing with an array of objects. Make sure that your second `.then` call is a function that contains all your success logic.

```js
fetch(url, options)
  .then((response) => response.json()) // parse JSON response
  .then((data) => {
    // do stuff with data (in this case an object[])
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err)); // handle errors
```

Here is a "working" demo. All you need to do is supply a valid API key.

```js
const apiHost = 'gamerpower.p.rapidapi.com';
const apiBaseUrl = `https://${apiHost}/api`
const apiKey = '<API-KEY>';
const defaultRequestConfig = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': apiKey,
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': apiHost
  }
};

const endpoint = `${apiBaseUrl}/giveaways?type=game&sort-by=popularity`;
fetch(endpoint, defaultRequestConfig)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(gamesList => {
    const ul = document.createElement('UL');
    gamesList.forEach(({ title }) => {
      ul.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('LI'), { innerText: title }));
    });
    document.querySelector('h2').after(ul);
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1>Current Game Giveaways</h1>
<button type="button" name="button">Get Burger</button>
<h2>Games</h2>
<img src="" alt="">
<h3>Description</h3>
```

Here is the `async`/`await` version:

```js
(async() => {
  const endpoint = `${apiBaseUrl}/giveaways?type=game&sort-by=popularity`;
  const gamesList = await fetch(endpoint, defaultRequestConfig)
    .then(response => response.json());
  const ul = document.createElement('UL');
  gamesList.forEach(({ title }) => {
    ul.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('LI'), { innerText: title }));
  });
  document.querySelector('h2').after(ul);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that uses `data` needs to be inside the `.then()` callback. You have it after the callback.

```js
fetch('https://gamerpower.p.rapidapi.com/api/giveaways?type=game&sort-by=popularity', gamesList)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data.gamesList);
    document.querySelector('h2').innerText = data.gamesList.title;
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```